# React Native show header and back button on drawer navigation screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I just add drawer navigation and works fine, but in options, there is not a headerShown as Stack has.

I created a few screen examples, and use tapbar, stack and drawer in the same file.+

I searched on some YouTubes and there is not a specific explanation

Thank you.

You can see my current app: [GIF HERE](https://media.giphy.com/media/M5QwnUMuwLf2RLaWhN/giphy.gif)

**HomeStack**

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />

      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**Drawer**

`````
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MainScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Leaderboards"
          component={Leaderboards}
          options={{
            drawerIcon: (config) => <AntDesign size={23} name="user" />,
          }}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Drawer screen has no header option. You can either make your own header component for your Leaderboards screen or nest a stack navigator that contains the Leaderboards screen within your drawer screen and customize the header through the options properties.